# Filter Range Copy Paste the Value and Create new Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have been trying to find an way to create multiple sheets using Specific Column data.

If Col"A" has multiple duplicate entries then filter single value create the new sheet using that value name, copy all the data and paste into newly added sheet.

I am unable to elaborate this thing in words and sorry for my poor English, i have attached an example workbook.

Where Sheet1 has data using Column A code will create multiple sheets. Your help will be much appreciated.

```
Sub CopyPartOfFilteredRange()
    Dim src As Worksheet
        Dim tgt As Worksheet
        Dim filterRange As Range
        Dim copyRange As Range
        Dim lastRow As Long
    
        Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet8")
    
        src.AutoFilterMode = False
    
        lastRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
        Set filterRange = src.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    
        Set copyRange = src.Range("A1:P" & lastRow)
    
        filterRange.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="CC"
    
        copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("A1")
    
    End Sub
```

**Data Sheet**
[image]

**CC New Sheet**
[image]

**DD New Sheet**
[image]

```
Till the last value HH
```

Comment: Please do not include links to your google drive in your question. Instead, provide a screenshot, or the relevant data in text/table form.

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: If you got Excel365 you may benefit from function FILTER to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next adapted code:

```
Sub CopyPartOfFilteredRange()
    Dim src As Worksheet, tgt As Worksheet, copyRange As Range, filterRange As Range, lastRow As Long
    Dim dict As Object, filterArr, i As Long
    
        Set src = ActiveSheet ' ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = src.Range("A" & src.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
        Set copyRange = src.Range("A1:P" & lastRow)
        Set filterRange = src.Range("A2:A" & lastRow) 'it assumes that there are headers on the first row
        filterArr = filterRange.value   'place it in an array for faster iteration
        
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 1 To UBound(filterArr)
            If filterArr(i, 1) <> "" Then dict(filterArr(i, 1)) = 1 'extract uniques strings
        Next
        filterArr = dict.Keys        'unique strings to be used in filterring
        'some optimization:
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        End With
        For i = 0 To UBound(filterArr)
            src.AutoFilterMode = False
            'insert the new sheet and name it as filterr criteria, or use the existing one, if any:
            On Error Resume Next
             Set tgt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(left(filterArr(i), 31))
             If err.Number = 0 Then 'if sheets already exists:
                tgt.cells.Clear            'clear its content and use it
             Else                           'if not, insert and name it:
                Set tgt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=src)
                If Len(filterArr(i)) > 31 Then filterArr(i) = left(filterArr(i), 31)
                tgt.Name = filterArr(i): err.Clear
             End If
            On Error GoTo 0
            filterRange.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=filterArr(i)
            copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("A1")
        Next i
        src.AutoFilterMode = False
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
            .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        End With
        MsgBox "Processed " & UBound(filterArr) & "PCP Provider Names..."
    End Sub
```

The above code has been updated to process the active sheet (and sheets on active workbook).

```
It needs a little optimization (`ScreenUpdating`, `EnableEvents`, `Calculation`) and check if the sheet with a specific name already exists, clearing all (in such a case) and reuse it, instead of inserting a new one.
```

Comment: Thank you your code works perfect but i have 400+ unique entries in column "A" and code through an error after adding 56th sheets. https://ibb.co/XJJwZPH

Comment: @ShRa This only mean that the filtering string contains at least one illegal character. Please, Press `Debug` and move the cursor over `filterArr(i)`. What does it show? It certainly contains one of the illegal characters (/, \, :, ?, [, ])... If only one such case, you may use `Replace` and use a legal character instead. I will show you how... Or a line of 6 `Replace` imbricated methods for all illegal chars. Replacing with "_", for instance...

Comment: Yes you are right `filterArr(i) = <Type mismatch>`

Comment: @ShRa Please, insert the next testing line: `Debug.print Join(filterArr, "|"): stop` and check if there are any space in the array (two consecutive "|"). If so, I will try filtering the aray...

Comment: Yes two or three string have this sgin `|`

Comment: @ShRa I am afraid you don't get it... That is the separator between the array elements. Only if two such consecutive characters appear, this mean that an empty string is there. But, are there empty cells in column A:A? If so, this must be the problem...

Comment: @ShRa I updated the code to skip the empty cells (if the case). Please, try the updated version.

Comment: I tested the code and `SAME` error is persisting

Comment: @ShRa If  not something confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion?  Eventually fill it with dummy data. It should be something related to your data to be processed. It works well on my test workbook.

Comment: No that data is very confidential i can share it through private source if possible.

Comment: @ShRa You can send it on my personal mail (in my profile).

Comment: No email in your profile @FaneDuru

Comment: @ShRa It is... Just below the icon, to the left side. Anyhow: ivangu@yahoo.com.

Comment: Yes thank you file sent

Comment: @ShRa Well, "Kimberly Sheryl Andrews-Reynolds" has more than 31 characters, as the error message states... Moving the cursor over what I said, you could see it. I adapted the code to keep only 31 characters, for such cases and it worked. I will send the processed workbook. But, your code used `ThisWorkbook`. Processing another workbook, it should use `ActiveWorkbook`. I will adapt the above code to work on the active workbook and with some optimization. Not immediately...

Comment: Can you please update the code @FaneDuru

Comment: @ShRa Updated it. With optimization, too. It takes less than 30 seconds, when most of the sheets already exist... Please, test it and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on here:

1. You want sheets named with the duplicate values in column A. First, you need the unique values, which you can find using the Unique function: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e
2. You need to pass those values into an array and then loop through each: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/loop-through-array/
3. Then you need to copy the values and paste to each new sheet which can be done with the autofilter and usedrange.
4. Then you need a lot error handling for sheets added or deleted.

Try this solution:

```
Sub CopyPartOfFilteredRange()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim UValues As Variant
    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim list As New Collection
    
    
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        If LastRow = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Worksheet contains no data"
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                End
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set myrange = sht.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    
    On Error Resume Next
        
        For Each Value In myrange
           list.Add CStr(Value), CStr(Value) 'extract unique strings
        Next
    On Error GoTo 0
        ReDim UValues(list.Count - 1, 0)
        
        For i = 0 To list.Count - 1
            UValues(i, 0) = list(i + 1)
        Next
    
    For i = LBound(UValues) To UBound(UValues)
        If Len(UValues(i, 0)) = 0 Then
            GoTo Nexti
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = UValues(i, 0)
                    If Err.Number = "1004" Then
                        On Error GoTo 0
                                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                                    MsgBox "Worksheet name " & UValues(i, 0) & " already taken"
                                        ActiveSheet.Delete
                                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                               
                        GoTo Nexti
                    Else
            On Error GoTo 0
                            sht.AutoFilterMode = False
                            sht.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=UValues(i, 0), VisibleDropDown:=False, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                            sht.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                             With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(UValues(i, 0))
                                .Range("A1").PasteSpecial ''Set this to appropriate sheet number
                             End With
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    End If
        End If
Nexti:
    Next i
sht.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but receiing an error `UValues = Application.WorksheetFunction.Unique(myrange) ''Uses the Unique Function
` Compile Error: Method or data number not found

Comment: `=Unique` must be only available in some versions. I updated my code above. I used List to create a collection. It runs quickly even when stretching the range to 500 rows

Comment: Took me a bit, but just tried it on 70,000 rows and it ran in about 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

### Create Unique Worksheets

- This will delete each possibly existing sheet before it will add a new worksheet and copy the filtered data to it.
- If a worksheet name exceeds the 31 character limit, its name will be truncated.
- If a worksheet name is invalid, it will not be renamed.

**The Solution**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyUniqueWorksheets()
    
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Copy Unique Worksheets"
    
    Dim dTime As Double: dTime = Timer ' time measuring
    Debug.Print "Started '" & ProcTitle & "' at '" & Now & "'." ' log
    
    Const swsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sCol As Long = 1
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(swsName)
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' Source Range
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count ' Source Rows Count
    
    If srCount < 2 Then Exit Sub ' just headers or no data at all
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = srg.Columns(sCol).Value
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim dKey As Variant
    Dim dString As String
    Dim r As Long
    
    ' Write the unique strings to a dictionary.
    For r = 2 To srCount
        dKey = sData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(dKey) Then
            If Len(dKey) > 0 Then
                dString = CStr(dKey)
                If StrComp(dString, swsName, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                    dict(dString) = Empty
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only blanks and error values and whatnot
    Erase sData
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim scrg As Range ' Source Copy Range
    
    Dim dws As Object
    Dim dwsName As String
    
    For Each dKey In dict.Keys
        ' Restrict to maximum allowed characters (31).
        dwsName = dKey
        If Len(dwsName) > 31 Then
            dwsName = Left(dwsName, 31)
            Debug.Print "'" & dKey & "' is too long." & vbLf _
                & "'" & dwsName & "' is used in the continuation." ' log
        End If
        ' Delete possibly existing sheet.
        On Error Resume Next
            Set dws = wb.Sheets(dwsName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not dws Is Nothing Then ' destination sheet exists
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            dws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'Else ' destination sheet doesn't exist
        End If
        ' Create a reference to a newly added (destination) worksheet.
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        ' Rename Destination Worksheet.
        On Error Resume Next
            dws.Name = dwsName
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then ' invalid sheet name
                ' log
                Debug.Print "'" & dwsName & "' cannot be used as a sheet name."
            'Else ' valid sheet name
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' Create a reference to the Source Copy Range.
        srg.AutoFilter sCol, dKey
        Set scrg = srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' headers are visible
        sws.AutoFilterMode = False
        ' Copy the Source Copy Range to the Destination Worksheet.
        scrg.Copy dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
        ' Initialize Destination Worksheet variable (reference).
        Set dws = Nothing
    Next dKey
        
    sws.Activate
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
Debug.Print "It took " & Timer - dTime & " seconds." ' time measuring
Debug.Print "Ended '" & ProcTitle & "' at '" & Now & "'." ' log
    
    MsgBox "Unique worksheets created.", vbInformation, ProcTitle

End Sub
```

**Barely Related**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a workbook ('wb'), deletes all sheets except the ones
'               whose names are in a list ('ExceptionsList').
' Remarks:      At least one of the remaining sheets has to be visible.
'               A very hidden sheet cannot be deleted.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub DeleteSheets()
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const ExceptionsList As String = "Sheet1"
    Const Delimiter As String = "," ' tied to 'ExceptionsList'
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Dim Exceptions() As String: Exceptions = Split(ExceptionsList, Delimiter)
    
    Dim sh As Object
    
    Dim ex As Long
    Dim IsFoundVisibleSheet
    For ex = 0 To UBound(Exceptions)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set sh = Nothing
        Set sh = wb.Sheets(Exceptions(ex))
        On Error GoTo ClearError
        If Not sh Is Nothing Then ' sheet exists
            If sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then ' sheet is visible
                IsFoundVisibleSheet = True
                Exit For
            'Else ' sheet is not visible
            End If
        'Else ' sheet doesn't exist
        End If
    Next ex
    If Not IsFoundVisibleSheet Then Exit Sub ' no remaining visible sheets
    
    Dim SheetNames() As String: ReDim SheetNames(1 To wb.Sheets.Count)
    Dim VeryHidden() As String: ReDim VeryHidden(1 To wb.Sheets.Count)
    
    Dim sn As Long
    Dim vh As Long
    
    Dim shName As String
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        shName = sh.Name
        If IsError(Application.Match(shName, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            sn = sn + 1
            SheetNames(sn) = shName
            If sh.Visible = xlVeryHidden Then
                vh = vh + 1
                VeryHidden(vh) = shName
            'Else ' sheet is not very hidden
            End If
        'Else ' sheet found in 'Exceptions'
        End If
    Next sh
    
    If sn = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no sheets to delete
    ReDim Preserve SheetNames(1 To sn)
    
    If vh > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve VeryHidden(1 To vh)
        For vh = 1 To vh
            wb.Sheets(VeryHidden(vh)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Next vh
    'Else ' no very hidden sheets
    End If
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
    wb.Sheets(SheetNames).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

**Initial (Old) Answer**

- The idea is valid, but it takes forever on OP's data.
- This will delete each possibly existing sheet before copying the source worksheet and renaming it. Then it will filter it to delete the undesired rows (not entire rows) of the table range in the copied worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyUniqueWorksheets()
    
    Const swsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sCol As Long = 1
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(swsName)
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' Table Range
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = srg.Columns(sCol) ' Column Range
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = scrg.Rows.Count
    Dim dcrgAddress As String: dcrgAddress = scrg.Address(0, 0)
    Dim sdrg As Range: Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srCount - 1).Offset(1) ' Data Range
    Dim ddrgAddress As String: ddrgAddress = sdrg.Address(0, 0)
    
    If srCount < 2 Then Exit Sub ' just headers or no data at all
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = scrg.Value
    
    Dim drgAddress As String: drgAddress = srg.Address(0, 0)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim dKey As Variant
    Dim dString As String
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 2 To srCount
        dKey = sData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(dKey) Then
            If Len(dKey) > 0 Then
                dString = CStr(dKey)
                If StrComp(dString, swsName, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                    dict(dString) = Empty
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dws As Object
    Dim drg As Range ' Delete Range
    Dim dcrg As Range ' Column Range
    Dim ddrg As Range ' Data Range
    
    For Each dKey In dict.Keys
        ' Delete possibly existing sheet.
        On Error Resume Next
            Set dws = wb.Sheets(dKey)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not dws Is Nothing Then ' destination sheet exists
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            dws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'Else ' destination sheet doesn't exist
        End If
        ' Copy source worksheet.
        sws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        Set dws = ActiveSheet
        ' Rename destination worksheet.
        On Error Resume Next
            dws.Name = dKey
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "'" & dKey & "' is an invalid sheet name.", vbExclamation
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' Delete rows.
        Set dcrg = dws.Range(dcrgAddress)
        Set ddrg = dws.Range(ddrgAddress)
        dcrg.AutoFilter 1, "<>" & dKey
        On Error Resume Next
            Set drg = ddrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        dws.AutoFilterMode = False ' to not delete entire rows
        If Not drg Is Nothing Then
            drg.Delete xlShiftUp
            Set drg = Nothing
        End If
        Set dws = Nothing
    Next dKey
        
    sws.Activate
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Unique worksheets created.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: The code is extremely slow the sheet got stuck `Not Responding` i do not not why

Comment: I have downloaded your workbook and it finishes almost instantly. I have modified the code in the meantime a little bit, so try to copy this current version. Maybe you are accidentally running one of the other codes? Note that my procedure is named `CopyUniqueWorksheets`.

Comment: The sheet yopu have downloaded is too little with data. The original sheet has 400+ `Unique`values in `ColA` and data is available from `A1 to AG90000`.

Comment: can i send this on your email which is available in your profile

Comment: file has been sent

Comment: I've tested my code and it works although it takes forever. You have 4 names that are longer than 31 characters, the limit of characters for a sheet name. You could consider creating new workbooks instead of new worksheets when this wouldn't matter. An improvement on my code would probably be to create a template worksheet containing only the headers and then copy it (the copy becoming the destination worksheet), filter the source worksheet, and copy the filtered data to the destination. I'll try that. You should think about what to do about the 4 too-long names and about the 'workbooks idea'.